# Creating a router with ESP32 and SIM800c

Tags: wifi, esp32, gps, tinygps, espressif

I am trying to create a device which is a combination of ESP32 and Sim800c.
This device (Master) will start AP mode on ESP32, so that other devices (Nodes) will connect to this AP. The Sim800c will provide 2G internet connection to the ESP32.
The nodes will be executing a HTTPS request and via this device (Master) the http request will gets executed and the response will be received via the Master device and again forwarded to the Node.

Basically this device which i am trying to create will act as a WiFi router which provides internet connection to the Nodes.

Hence my question is, will this device work as expected.

Comment: yes, such a device should work

Comment: @jsotola : thanks for the quick response. i have a query here, you have written should work in your comment. Can u reply with the possible challenges you think will occur.

Comment: it is unknown if you have the skill to develop the necessary code

Comment: Sure you can write code that will receive a request over WiFi in some format that you specify, then make a HTTPS request over 2G, and send the response back over WiFi. It won't be simple code, and you have to remember that it's the "server" node that has to make the HTTPS request, not the "client" nodes.